# Trimming my data and can not overcome error

Tags: r, function

## Truncated version of the data

```
truncate1 <- function(x, prop=.01) {
             trimx <- x[x < quantile(x,prob=(1-prop))]
             return(trimx)
}
```

## Truncation version of the data

```
TRU_BANK <- as.data.frame(BANK)
```

## Winsorization of the independent variables to control for outlier

```
TRU_BANK$VaR <- truncate1(BANK$TVAR_AVG)

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "VaR", value = c(19.6, 35.2, 26.9,  : 
replacement has 501 rows, data has 507
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the vector that returns from your function doesn't have the same number of items that the one it takes. Using this code, it will add NAs so your function returns same numbers of items as its argument, and it can be assigned to another column of the data.frame:

```
truncate1 <- function(x, prop=.01) { 
    trimx <- rep(NA, length(x))
    trimx[x < quantile(x,prob=(1-prop))]<- x[x < quantile(x,prob=(1-prop))]
    return(trimx)
}
TRU_BANK$VaR <- truncate1(BANK$TVAR_AVG)
```

Another solution if you want to remove the outliers from the data.frame is returning an index of the rows you want to keep, then filter the data.frame:

```
truncate2 <- function(x, prop=.01) { 
    trimx <- x < quantile(x,prob=(1-prop))
    return(trimx)
}
TRU_BANK <- BANK[truncate2(BANK$TVAR_AVG),]
```

Comment: But is not the whole point of trimming that I exclude the outliers?

Comment: If you really remove some elements, you will have less items than in your original data.frame, so you can not store it in another column (all columns must have same number of items).